# 'Double' missing from VertexAttribPointerType enum in OpenTK 1.0?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, opentk

I'm trying to specify the type of my `GL.VertexAttribPointer(...)` argument as `GL_DOUBLE`. This should be valid according to the documentation for this OpenTK function for ES20 ([link](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_graphics_1_1_e_s20_1_1_g_l.html#ac7f5076b6e3684192508d22342ddd4e1)).

However, the `VertexAttribPointerType` enum seems to be missing the `Double` type for OpenTK-1.0. In other words, the following line:

```
GL.VertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_COORD2D, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Double, false, 0, quadVertices);
```

..fails to compile since the `VertexAttribPointerType` only provides the definitions for the following:

```
using System;
namespace OpenTK.Graphics.ES20
{
    public enum VertexAttribPointerType
    {
        Byte = 5120,
        UnsignedByte,
        Short,
        UnsignedShort,
        Float = 5126,
        Fixed = 5132
    }
}
```

Is there a work around for this issue? How else are you supposed to specify a `double[]` of vertices for the vertex shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL ES 2.0 [manual page for glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) says:

> GL_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_SHORT, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, GL_FIXED, or
>   GL_FLOAT are accepted

So the reason for OpenTK not having double is that the underlying framework doesn't seem to support it either. The OpenTK documentation may be suffering from copy-paste error.